# Remote TeX from Windows RT

Tags: compiling, windows

I have picked up a Surface RT and while there are LaTeX editors in the Microsoft store, nothing exists in terms of compilation.

Is there a way I can save a `.tex` file on my Surface but send it to a remote location for compilation? By remote, I was thinking of my old desktop with Ubuntu on it.

**EDIT:** I've decided to stay on Windows 7 using Miktex and Skydrive. Is there a solution with these products?

Comment: If you install Dropbox you could probably write a script that runs a compilation whenever the file is updated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run a simple script on Ubuntu that would watch for a change in a LaTeX file on (for example) Dropbox and then compiles it:

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -e modify ~/Dropbox/compileme.tex
do
        pdflatex -interaction batchmode ~/Dropbox/compileme.tex
done
```

You just need to run that script in the background on your Ubuntu pc.

Comment: I've decided to stay on Windows 7 using Miktex and Skydrive. Is there a solution with these products?